EFCore with .Net framework 4.8
I've tries to google for a while, but couldn't find a clear up-to-date answer...
I have a .net 4.8 application and I want to add EntityFrameworkCore to it.
From what I read it seemed that EFCore 3.x used to support .Net framework 4 but it isn't supported anymore?
What version of EFCore should I use?

There is no supported version of EF Core that works with .NET Framework.

There is also the non-core EntityFramework, or do you want to use specific EFCore functionality?

@HansKeﬆing In fact, what is most important to me is the BulkExtensions, which as I see - depends on EFCore. Is there also a non-core package for bulk operations?

All the answers are clear and up-to-date. EF Core targets .NET Core, not .NET Framework.  The only versions that worked with .NET Framework are no longer supported

@mich what do you mean BulkExtensions and why do you need them? It matters, because either the functionality was always available in ADO.NET itself and Dapper, or you refer to a misleading feature from a third-party NuGet package that essentially writes to a temporary table before updating the target. EF Core 8's ExecuteUpdate and ExecuteDelete are little more than query builders that execute UPDATE or DELETE queries using ADO.NET. You could easily do the same with a SQL builder library, like Dapper's. True bulk inserts (ie minimally logged, fast) were always possible using SqlBulkCopy

@mich There's also a third-party NuGet that doesn't really do the bulk operations it clams. Its "bulk insert" is a wrapper over SqlBulkCopy, nothing more.  The "bulk update" operation isn't that at all. It transfers data using SqlBulkCopy to a temporary table, then transfers new or modified rows to the target using UPDATE target ...FROM source INNER JOIN target etc, like any data transfer script would. It's slower than any script though because you can't control the indexes, compression or storage of the temporary table, or perform easy transformations in the queries

Look at linq2db orm. IMHO, it's more powerful than anything else. It also supports bulk operations.

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comments. I somehow missed out Dapper... now I absolutly fine without using EF/EFCore at all.

From the documentation EF Core releases and planning :


EF Core 2.1 will continue to be supported when used with ASP.NET Core 2.1 on .NET Framework only. See ASP.NET Support Policy for details.


But EF Core 2.1 lacks a lot of functionality and the documentation was removed. I don't recommend to use it.

At my work, I use EF Core 3.1 with .NET Framework, it's work fine. But the support of this version is ended, so check your work policies first.
A alternative is to use the old EF6... or best migrate to new .NET.

EF Core 3 reached End Of Life along with .NET Core 3.1 and wasn't exactly fine - it was the first version that didn't resort to client-side evaluation silently. It still lacked a lot of the functionality found in EF "Classic" 6. If you're still on 3.1, you're on unsupported software
